# Update Marker from Firebase

Tags: java, android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a map application.

This application has buttons, which if pressed, add a marker on the map and is added to LatLang in Firebase.

My Firebase is structured like this:

[Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reaOS.png)

This is my application screen:

[Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY3Kq.png)

I'm having difficulty when the marker is dragged. I can get LatLang, but I can not send it to Firebase, and also if I update some data in Firebase, it does not update in the App, only if I close and open the App again.

How can I do this ?

```
@Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {

            LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();

            String id = marker.getId();

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+latLng+id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Marker previousMarker = mMarkerMap.get(marker.getId());

            if (previousMarker != null) {
                marker.remove();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().draggable(true).position(latLng).title("Buraco").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.road)));
            } else {
                marker.remove();
                mDatabase.push().setValue(latLng);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
            LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
            marker.setPosition(latLng);
        }
    });

    GPS();

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Locais").child("Buraco");

    mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
            LatLng location = new LatLng(
                    dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(double.class),
                    dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(double.class)

            );
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().draggable(true).position(location).title("Buraco").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.road)));
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently only handing `onChildAdded`, which fires:

1. Initially for very existing child node.
2. Whenever a new child node is added.

If you update an existing node, neither of those is true, to `onChildAdded` doesn't fire. Instead `onChildChanged` will fire for such an update, so you'll have to implement that, read the lat and lon, and update the marker.